# GitHub Action Vitest CI pipeline

Tags: github-actions, vite, vitest

I would like to create a *CI pipeline* with GitHub Action but I have problems. The front end of the project is developed in **Vue 3** and uses **vitest** to run the tests. It's in a folder called "WEB" in the root directory. So I would like to run my tests at each commit in the master branch but it returns this error:

```
Error: .github#L1
each step must define a `uses` or `run` key
```

I used the preexisting "Node.js" template and just added the "working-directory" property to specify the "WEB" folder.

Here is my ".yml" file

```
name: Runs frontend tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        working-directory: ./WEB
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Execute Unit tests
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a `-` it add an element at the `steps` array:

You should do it like this:

```
- name: Execute Unit tests
  run: |
    npm ci
    npm run test
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a new error:
```
Error: Dependencies lock file is not found in /home/runner/work/projet-integration/projet-integration. Supported file patterns: package-lock.json,npm-shrinkwrap.json,yarn.lock
```

**project-integration** is the name of my github repository.
I think it did not take into account the change of my directory.

Comment: I think this is an other error. You should validate this answer and open a new issue :)

Comment: How can i post the output as a pull request comment ?